# || not short circuiting

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
private static readonly char[] wordSeparators = { ' ', ',', '.', '(', ')', '\'', '\"', '@', '\r', '\n' };

private bool _matchWholeWord = false;

public bool MatchWholeWord
{
    get { return _matchWholeWord; }
    set
    {
        if (_matchWholeWord != value)
        {
            _matchWholeWord = value;
            _isNewSearch = true;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

private bool IsFullWord(string textToSearchIn, int length, int index)
{
    return MatchWholeWord
        && wordSeparators.Contains(textToSearchIn[index + length])
        && (index == 0 || wordSeparators.Contains(textToSearchIn[index - 1]));
}
```

The problem is that when I call the function IsFullWord() with index = 0, it gives me an Index out of bounds error, even tho the first condition from `index == 0 || wordSeparators.Contains(textToSearchIn[index - 1])` is true. Why does't the || short circuit work?

Comment: I bet it is actually `length` which is out of bounds in that case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve] - we can't reproduce it with just the snippets here. But I think it's vanishingly unlikely that the cause if `||` not working properly.

Comment: It's infinitely more likely that `textToSearchIn[index + length]` is what actually throwing the exception than a bug in c#'s `||` operator.

Comment: (I'd also suggest getting Visual Studio to format your code using the default style before posting in Stack Overflow. While you're absolutely welcome to prefer your own bracing style, when you post on Stack Overflow it's useful to make it as readable as possible for as many readers as possible, which means the default style.0

Comment: Where's the code that calls `IsFullWord`? If I call it with `IsFullWord("", 56, 129)` then I get `IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.`. Until we know how you're calling it we can't really help.

Comment: @TanveerBadar you are right. It was index + length that was causing the problem. I was calling the function like this IsFullWord("test", 4, 0).